# Code is running when debugger stop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssh

I'm connecting to an ssh server when my application starts. Therefor I'm using the SSH.net Library. When I start Visual Studio and open the main wpf view Visual Studio is starting this connection in background even when my program is not running. So when I start my program with the debugger I get an "Only one usage of each socket address" exception.
I have Visual Studio 2010 + Wpf + Caliburn Micro running.

Why is Visual Studio doing that?

Regards Markus

Comment: Sounds like VS has to evaluate something in the process of rendering your form that's setting it off.  My first guess is that the way in which the connection is initiated could be modified to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the *Visual Studio Designer* is opening the connection when you open the window.
Probably because the function that opens the connection is in the constructor, which is called by the designer to show the window...

Add the following code in the function that opens the SSH connection to *prevent* the connection from opening if you're in the designer:

```
bool isInDesignMode = System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
if (isInDesignMode)
     return;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Just an info: When I put the SSH connect method into the bootstrapper, then Visual Studio is starting it. When I put it in the main constructor, it's not starting.